# How to replace community edition sonarqube aws instance to developer edition?

Tags: amazon-ec2, sonarqube, bitnami

I am new to sonarqube. I have created bitnami sonarqube community instance. However, it does not support swift scanner. To execute swift scanner I want to update my bitnami sonarqube community instance to developer instance. Where do I need to change the setting?

I checked marketplace where developer edition option is redirected to sonarqube page which notifies sonarqube support will be contacting soon.

I have developer license key, but don't know where to apply.

Comment: The software is the same. The license key is used to activate the right edition. Login as admin.

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami Engineer here. You can replace the Sonarqube files with the Developer edition to start using it. These are the steps

- Stop the services

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh stop
```

- Backup the current installation

```
sudo mv /opt/bitnami/apps/sonarqube/sonarqube/ /opt/bitnami/apps/sonarqube/sonarqube-backup/
```

- Copy the new files to the /opt/bitnami/apps/sonarqube/sonarqube/ directory
- Update the contents of the /opt/bitnami/apps/sonarqube/sonarqube/conf/sonar.properties and /opt/bitnami/apps/sonarqube/sonarqube/conf/wrapper.conf files with the settings of the related files in the /opt/bitnami/apps/sonarqube-backup/sonarqube/conf backup directory. To do so, use an editor to modify them with the old settings (web server URL, database, LDAP settings, etc.).

> NOTE: Edit the settings files manually. Do not copy-paste the old files.

- Restore the permissions.

```
sudo chown -R root:sonarqube /opt/bitnami/apps/sonarqube/sonarqube
```

- Verify that the plugins you have are compatible with the new version
- Restart SonarQube

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart sonarqube
```

- Browse to http://SERVER-IP/setup and follow the setup instructions

More information here: https://docs.bitnami.com/general/apps/sonarqube/administration/upgrade/#upgrade-only-sonarqube-in-the-bitnami-sonarqube-stack

Comment: Hi Jota. I am new to aws can you please tell where to write that commands, please?

Comment: You will need to connect through SSH to the instance and then run the commands there. You should have the SSH key to use so depending on the OS you are using you will need to follow different steps to access to the instance https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/get-started/connect-ssh/

Comment: Hi Jota, I checked sonar.properties everything is the same. Can you please mention which section is needed to be updated?

Comment: I have a license key for developer edition so where can I update that on bitnami community instance running on aws.